# How to add main menu to application?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I know that an application template comes with default 'Main Menu' items already existing and attached.

But if this default 'Main Menu' structure was deleted then how to re-add main menu items to the application? Simply adding fresh menu items tree to XIB and connecting it to the application's window 'menu' outlet using the visual connector does not make these menu items to appear in the application main menu - application menu bar still stays empty.

What is the right way to add menu to application?

Comment: That's an interesting question.  One way of doing it is to copy one from another project, I guess.

Comment: To do it programmatically, the menu is set using NSApplication's `mainMenu`.  There are also a few special menus that have their own property, such as `windowsMenu` and `helpMenu`.

Comment: The application's window 'menu' outlet is a context menu, don't connect it to the menu bar.